# Java Password Checking

Tags: java

The problem I am having is having it repeat the first password process before confirming the password.

> The password must be at least 8 characters long.
>
> The password must contain at least:
>
> - one alpha character `[a-zA-Z]`
> - one numeric character `[0-9]`
> - one character that is not alpha or numeric, such as
>               `! # @ $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ = + [ ] ; : ' " , < . > / ?`
>
> The password must not:
>
> - contain spaces
> - begin with an exclamation `[!]` or a question mark `[?]`

Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare variables
    String inputPassword;       // variable for password
    String confirmPassword;

    // set up input stream from the keyboard
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    // ask for password
    System.out.print("Password : ");
    inputPassword = input.next();
    passCheck(inputPassword);

    System.out.print("Please confirm your password : ");
    confirmPassword = input.next();


    if(inputPassword.matches(confirmPassword)){
        System.out.println("Password successfully created.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Passwords do not match.");
    }


}

public static void passCheck(String password){
    boolean valid = true;
    if(password.length() < 8){
        System.out.println("Password is not eight characters long.");
        valid = false;
    }
    String upperCase = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
    if(!password.matches(upperCase)){
        System.out.println("Password must contain at least one capital letter.");
        valid = false;
    }
    String numbers = "(.*[0-9].*)";
    if(!password.matches(numbers)){
        System.out.println("Password must contain at least one number.");
        valid = false;
    }
    String specialChars = "(.*[ ! # @ $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ = + [ ] ; : ' \" , < . > / ?].*)";
    if(!password.matches(specialChars)){
        System.out.println("Password must contain at least one special character.");
        valid = false;
    }
    String space = "(.*[   ].*)";
    if(password.matches(space)){
        System.out.println("Password cannot contain a space.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(password.startsWith("?")){
        System.out.println("Password cannot start with '?'.");
        valid = false;

    }
    if(password.startsWith("!")){
        System.out.println("Password cannot start with '!'.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(valid){
        System.out.println("Password is valid.");
    }
}
```

What I'm getting is after it tells me one of the problems, it'll ask to confirm password, which isn't what I want.

Comment: You could use `[^A-Za-z0-9]` for non-alphanumeric.

Comment: return the validity of the password (a boolean, for example) from passCheck. So that, in main, you can test the boolean before proceeding.

Comment: A password with spaces, question marks, and exclamation points is stronger than one that does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the password is invalid, there is no need for the user to repeat the password

my take on this;

```
  System.out.print("Password : ");
    inputPassword = input.next();


   if(passCheck(inputPassword))
    {
    System.out.print("Please confirm your password : ");
    confirmPassword = input.next();


          if(inputPassword.matches(confirmPassword)){
           System.out.println("Password successfully created.");
          } else {
          System.out.println("Passwords do not match.");
           }
    }
    else {....}
```

.......

edit: i noticed that the return type of your method passCheck is void. try changing that to boolean

Comment: The else at the end gives me an error saying 'else' without 'if' when the if is above it.

Comment: sorry, remove the semi-colon at the end of if

Comment: also, click the check button if you're satisfied with my answer. lemme know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `passCheck()` method's return type to `boolean` and return the value of its local `valid` variable at the end:

```
public static boolean passCheck(String password){
    // ...
    if(valid){
        System.out.println("Password is valid.");
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Then in `main()` you can check its return value and exit immediately, if password is invalid, without asking for confirmation password.

```
//...
// ask for password
System.out.print("Password : ");
inputPassword = input.next();
if(!passCheck(inputPassword)) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you never tell the code to break if the password is not the correct format. What I would suggest is changing the return type of your passCheck() method to boolean, and adding

```
return valid;
```

to the very end of it.

Then, use a do-while loop to continuously ask for the password until it matches, as such:

```
do{
  System.out.print("Password : ");
  inputPassword = input.next();
}while(!passCheck(inputPassword));
```

This will confirm that the program does not continue until the password is the correct format.